# Recovering non booting system, probably due to power failure

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, chroot, void-linux

I cycled the power on my Void Linux install when Firefox froze and would not respond to sigterm (poweroff command was hanging too).

After doing this the computer (Thinkpad X220) no longer boots, it hangs on the thinkpad splash screen. Grub menu doesnt even display.

To try and remedy this I used a live void linux usb and boot from that (had to remove harddrive and then stick it in once it boots to usb).

Then I try the following to fix grub:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
chroot /mnt
```

However chroot fails with "can't find /bin/sh".

If anyone has any insight into this problem to offer, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I do not know about Void Linux, but other distributions I know usually have some kind of repair options on their installation media. Thy to use that options if it is available, See how many partitions you have, and which ones need repair. It might be a hardware failure, especialy if you have UEFI boot partition. It would be strange that UEFI partition would be corrupt by regular work, even with unexpected power failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have  to send this as answer because of no note rights...

Since you are trying to mount the drive as a directory /mnt itself, I am assuming you to be a beginner.
Its more common to create a directory inside mnt and then mount into it.

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/HDrive
```

You should try to use gparted.
Not sure if your live USB contains gparted, but if it doesn't get a live USB which does.
(mine personal favourite is sysrescueCD)

If you are booting from other drive it is unlikely that your old HD is still sda (that is usually the disk you are booting from) and its far more likely to be sdb.
When you open Gparted it shows you available drives. Chose the original hard-drive but look at sizes of a disk as its name is likely to have changed. gparted will let you check and fix the actual partitions for errors. this alone might help. if not then only after checking and fixing partitions, should you even bother reinstalling grub. Firefox has no means of accessing boot partition and cant edit anything outside your home directory and /tmp so its far more likely to be a HD drive error which might have been what froze firefox rather then other way round.
If gparted doesn't give you two drives to chose from (top right not really a corner) then your HD might be faulty.

Comment: I am indeed fairly newbish when it comes to this aspect of linux. I've been an end user for a long time(bash boi basically) tho. Marking this as the answer.